# Warning message 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 16 rows in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, predict

I am suppose to use the predict function to predict when `fjbjor` is 5.5 and I always get this warning message and I have tried many ways but it always comes so is there anyone who can see what I am doing wrong here

This is my code

```
fit.lm <- lm(fjbjor~amagn, data=bjor)
summary(fit.lm)

new.bjor<- data.frame(fjbjor=5.5)
predict(fit.lm,new.bjor)
```

and this comes out

```
 1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11 
5.981287 2.864521 9.988559 5.758661 4.645530 2.419269 4.645530 5.313409 6.871792 3.309773 4.200278 

      12       13       14       15       16 
3.755026 5.981287 5.536035 1.974016 3.755026
```

> Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 16 rows

If anyone can see what is wrong I would be really thankful for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is `fjbjor ~ amagn`, where `fjbjor` is response and `amagn` is covariate. Then your `newdata` is `data.frame(fjbjor=5.5)`.

`newdata` should be used to provide covariates rather than response. `predict` will only retain columns of covariates in `newdata`. For your specified `newdata`, this will be `NULL`. As a result, `predict` will use the internal model frame for prediction, which returns you fitted values.

The warning message is fairly clear. `predict` determines the expected number of predictions from `nrow(newdata)`, which is 1. But then what I described above happened so 16 fitted values are returned. Such mismatch produces the warning.

---

Looks like the model you really want is: `amagn ~ fjbjor`.

Comment: Thank you very much :) do you know what I need to add to find the 95% prediction interval at 5.5 ?